# How do Duct Taped weapons fire?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

How does the item Duct Tape work? By that I mean to ask **what are the results of combining the different types of weapons in terms of firing the weapon** (and not in terms of the weapon's specific effects).

Due to the rareness of finding the Duct Tape item, it is difficult to check the possible combinations. And I hope that by asking here, players that have encountered a particular combination can give an answer for that combination.

I shall describe the combination as the primary weapon type* first, followed by the secondary weapon. The primary weapon is what appears when you wield, while the secondary is duct-taped to it.

What happens when:

1. Same type with Same type (E.g. Automatic with Automatic)

   - What happens when one has a larger clip size than the other? Does the smaller clip stop partway?
2. Automatic(Primary) with Charged(Secondary) Type

   - Will the Charged weapon fire? Does it fire upon release of the trigger as a charged weapon usually does?
3. Charged with Automatic

   - Will the Automatic weapon fire as I'm charging?
4. Beam with Automatic

   - Will the Automatic stop partway as its clip ends before the Beam-type?
5. Beam with Burst

   - Will the Burst only occur once if I'm holding down the trigger for the Beam?

---

Here is my guess on how duct tape works. I think it simply uses the same keypresses and durations of keypresses for both weapons simultaneously as though the weapons were there independently.

That is to say that for case 2 above, the charged weapon stays charged as the automatic weapon is firing, and fires the charged shot upon release. And for case 3, the automatic weapon fires as the charge is being held. However, I'm not sure since I have not encountered the Duct Tape item enough.

---

*Primer on Weapon Types:

- Automatic: Continuous fire as long as trigger is held down.
- Semiautomatic: Continuous fire as trigger is held down, may be possible to increase rate of fire by tapping trigger faster depending on the particular weapon.
- Beam: Continuous fire as long as trigger is held down. Clip size equals to ammo capacity.
- Charged: Fires upon release of trigger after being held down a set time.
- Burst: Fires a number of shots from the clip in a single press of the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

For all duct tape items, you get free reloads for every weapon other than the first, so if you get, for example, a beam type gun first, all subsequent guns will reload freely until you run out of ammo of the beam type gun, which then reloads and refills all of the others.. the weapons will all fire automatically while holding down the trigger, except the charged weapons, which will fire upon release of the trigger. This is my interpretation from what i've seen and experienced. It may be wrong, but from what i've seen that's what i think. This is probably way too late and you forgot about this, but i hope it helps.